# Create Windows 7 Intallation DVD from Existing installation

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation, waik

Is it possible to create a windows installation DVD from an existing Windows Installation?
I just wanted a software like Remastersys On Ubuntu.
Even if the other softwares are not saved, its OK.

Is it Possible with WAIK?

Comment: What would you want to save from the current installation then? Are you trying to emulate the dist or upgrade option of Remastersys?

Comment: I dont want to download the windows Updates again and again. That is the main reason.

Comment: You can use imagex, its part of Microsoft's WAIK package, see this turoial, it shows how to make a recovery partition, you could use the files in the partition you make to create a install DVD, but making the DVD is beyond the scope of this tutorial but will get you close to your goal...http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/21978-Windows-7-OEM-Recovery-Partition-tools-creator-Free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways to go about this - I tend to maintain a seperate disc of updates made with [wsus offline updates](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) and run that right after install to patch things up (which should save the effort of downloading the files each time.Its not automagical or as fast as the other two methods, but its flexible and faster than downloading all the patches one by one.

Otherwise, you can slipstream patches right into an install disk with a tool like [rt7lite](http://www.rt7lite.com/) but apparently you need to use [msu files to slipstream into the system](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/how-to-build-a-slipstream-windows-7-install-disc-715117) which [seems like a lot of work](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/147150-windows-update-download-standalone-msu-installer-file.html)

If its always to the same system, you can also simply get a baseline system, patch it, and image it, and simply restore it with a tool of your choice, like clonezilla

Comment: Thank you for your answer. wsus offline updates is a good idea. I was also thinking about using clonezilla, but it just backup the system. Suppose I don't want additional softwares and junk files etc.

Comment: Hai, wsus offline updates is for downloading the updates right. Can I use already downloaded updates

Comment: unfortunately no, you need to download all of them the first time

Comment: I got the windows Update Download utility which can download updates after SP1. www.windowsupdatesdownloader.com